# Validation of visible text field in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some hidden text fields in my table which become visible one by one when I click the add button. I want to validate(in rails) only those rows which are visible.

```
<div class="info_type">
        Internet<hr>
        <table id="email_add">
          <tr id="email_1">
            <th><%= f.label(:email1,"Email :") %></th>
            <td><input id="contact_email1" type="text" name="contact[email1]"></input>
            </td>
         </tr>
          <tr id="email_2">
            <th><%= f.label(:email2,"Email 2:") %></th>
            <td><input id="contact_email2" type="text" name="contact[email2]"></input>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="email_3">
            <th><%= f.label(:email3,"Email 3:") %></th>
            <td><input id="contact_email3" type="text" name="contact[email3]"></input>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" id="add_email" value="Add Email"/>
        <input type="button" id="delete_email" value="Delete Email"/>
      </div>
```

I hide rows email_2 and email_3 using jquery and display when add is clicked.
Is there any method of checking the text field visibility while using validates email tag or will I have to do it in jquery only??

Comment: You want validations to run on email_2 and email_3 if their fields are visible, correct?  How about just run validations but allow blank values?

Comment: Try what jcm has suggested

Answer (score 0):

Send a list of the hidden fields to the request then in the create method you can remove the fields you do not want to save from the params before you save.

To determine the hidden fields use JQuery's `$("#contact_email1").is(":visible")`

Then in the controller before saving remove the hidden elements variables using `params[:info].delete :email1` or `params.delete :email1` depending where it is located.

So, just create a list using some logic to keep track of the hidden elements, possibly by just using an int.  Then iterate over that list and remove them from the params.